# How can I create a Method to create a database Record using Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript

I need to create a method to create a databaserecord. I have no idea how to work on javascript that's why I'am looking for someone who can help me out. Thank you.

values are Thank you.

(layerNo, tableID, itemID, type, keyValue)

Comment: are you developing ASP.NET project? or something else? what is the database? what have you tried so far? you may need the help of Ajax if you need to update the database from javascript, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729129/update-sql-database-from-client-side-in-asp-net

Comment: I'm using C#.net.. I'm using sql for the database. I haven't tried anything yet as I just got the project today.

Comment: If this is an existing project, you may want to use similar data access methods already used in the application.  You say you're using C#, yet in your title you say that you're trying to write to the database using Javascript.  Can you please clarify how you envision the application working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a method to check dabatabase Record using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941777/creating-a-method-to-check-dabatabase-record-using-javascript)

Comment: You have [already asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941777/creating-a-method-to-check-dabatabase-record-using-javascript). If you need to add more details, please edit your old question instead of creating a duplicate question.

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit confusing. The specs that I'm currently following is written in Japanese. I will get back again when I ask my boss about the application and how things work. But I would like to say thank you for answering my questions although it is really confusing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The database will be updated from your C# code. Javascript might communicate the data to the web application (written in C#). The web app would typically perform the actual update. For a C# / ASP.NET web application, this could be done using ADO.NET or by using Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask you some other time again? I just need to clarify some more things to my boss regarding my project. Thank you